# Ошибка при запросе mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ошибка: 
Error! ----> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Код:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['reason_vip_lid']))
{

    $id_lid=htmlspecialchars($_POST['id_lid']); 
    $user=htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']); 
    $reason_vip_lid='VIP для объявления "Ищу лидера"';




    include("bd.php");

    $res22=mysql_query("UPDATE `gta_lid` SET `vip`='1' WHERE `id`='$id_lid'");
    $res33=mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `balance`=(`balance` - '20') WHERE `id`='$user'");
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transactions` (`user_id`,`reason`,`money`,`plmi`) VALUES('$user','$reason_vip_lid','20','0')");

    $result=mysql_query($query);

    if($result==true)
    {
        $_SESSION['add_ad'] = '10';
        header("location: myserv.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error! ----> ". mysql_error();
    }
}
?>
```

в чем трабл?

Comment: определитесь для начала в каком из трех запросов ошибка. там глядишь и понятнее будет. а еще поудмайте, что такое у вас `$result = mysql_query($query)` где `$query = mysql_query(....)`

Comment: 1) Укажите точно, в какой строке кода ошибка. 2) Цитируйте сообщение об ошибке полностью. 3) Вместо `mysql_query("запрос");` cделайте `$sql="запрос";mysql_query($sql);`, и покажите текст проблемного запроса.

Comment: ошибка в запросе `1`, на строке `$result=mysql_query($query);`.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка, полагаю в неправильной подстановке переменных.

Правильно в Вашем случае - ' ".$var." '
Вот код:

```
$res22 = mysql_query("UPDATE gta_lid SET vip='1' WHERE id='".$id_lid."'");
$res33 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `balance`=(`balance` - '20') WHERE 
    id='".$user."'");
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (`user_id`,`reason`,`money`,`plmi`) 
    VALUES('".$user."','".$reason_vip_lid."','20','0')");
```

*Вообще лучше использовать mysqli_query. А ещё лучше (в плане безопасности) PDO, но она сложнее, потребуется время чтобы вникнуть.*